# How to get a graph that shows the differences of occurences beetwen 2 months in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb

[image: SalesHeaders example]

I have a Collection in MongoDB called SalesHeaders and i want to create a graph in MongoDB Charts that displays the difference of sales beetwen a month and the previous month. Example: if in January the store has 100 sales and in February has 60 sales, in February should show -40.

How can I create the graph that displays those differences?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to make it easier for the cluster, I'd prepare the data in a dedicated collection. From your sample, I understand that you have a collection that contains the invoices. Based on that, you could fill another collection, e.g. `sales_by_month` with the count and the delta for the months.

As a sample, this aggregation pipeline groups the invoices by month and merges the resulting documents into the `sales_by_month` collection:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        $dateTrunc: {
          date: "$date",
          unit: "month"
        }
      },
      cnt: {
        $sum: 1
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$setWindowFields": {
      "partitionBy": null,
      "sortBy": {
        "_id": 1
      },
      "output": {
        "prev": {
          $first: "$cnt",
          window: {
            documents: [
              -1,
              -1
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $set: {
      delta: {
        $subtract: [
          "$cnt",
          "$prev"
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $unset: "prev"
  },
  {
    $merge: {
      into: "sales_by_month",
      whenMatched: "discard",
      whenNotMatched: "insert"
    }
  }
])
```

This pipeline first groups the sales by month and calculates the number of sales per month. Afterwards, it applies the `$setWindowFields` stage to retrieve the count of the previous month so that the following `$set` stage can calculate the delta between the months. As a last step, the documents are merged into the collection `sales_by_month` if the value does not exist yet.

Please note that above sample should give you a general idea and can be optimized further. For instance, you should limit the amount of sales that are included in the pipeline so that the `$group` stage does not have to handle documents in the past that are not required anymore.

Depending on your requirements, you could only take the sales of the last months into account and run the pipeline once a month or daily. One option for this is to use MongoDB Atlas Triggers.

With the `sales_by_month` collection in place, creating the chart does not differ from any other chart.

See this [mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Ix8xWUC10Gg) to test.